# Set a hook after storing variable in device memory

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a component I have the following statement:

```
const [home, setHome]=useState(false)

if(home){

return(<Redirect push={true} to="/" />);
}

setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user)
setHome(true)
```

That is, after the variable with the "isRegistered" flag is saved, home is equal to true and you must return to the home view. The problem is that start is rendered before the variable "isRegistered" is saved. How can I set home = true after the variable is actually stored in storage?

The setItem function is defined as follows:

```
export async function setItem(key: string, value: any) {
  await Storage.set({
    key: key,
    value: value
  });
 }
```

I have tried as follows:

```
setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user).then(() =>{
setHome(true)
})
```

But without success

Comment: See [Revisiting Hooks implementation #32](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/32)

Answer (score 0):

setItem is asynchronous method, use await when your call setItem.

```
await setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user)
setHome(true)
```

Hope this will give you success